# OpenCV 3.0 Linkage error with SURF, using visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, opencv, surf

I am trying to implement feature matching using SURF, but I keep getting this fatal error, all header files have been included, along with the library and paths have been defined. Here is my code along with screen shots of the error.I know this question has been asked many times and people have answered it by saying that one should include xfeaatures2d library, which I have included.

[image]

```
#include "opencv2\opencv_modules.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include"opencv2\highgui\include\opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include"opencv2\imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\xfeatures2d\include\opencv2\xfeatures2d\nonfree.hpp"
#include "opencv2\xfeatures2d\include\opencv2\xfeatures2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2\videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2\nonfree.hpp"
#include "opencv2\xfeatures2d.hpp"
using namespace cv;

void readme();

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

if (argc != 3)
{
    readme(); return -1;
}
Mat img_1,img_2;
img_1 = imread("DSC_0112.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
img_2 = imread("DSC_0112.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

if (!img_1.data || !img_2.data)
{
    printf(" --(!) Error reading images \n"); return -1;
}

//-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
int minHessian = 400;
Ptr<xfeatures2d::SURF> surf = xfeatures2d::SURF::create(minHessian);
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1,keypoints_2;

surf->detect(img_1, keypoints_1);
surf->detect(img_2, keypoints_2);

//-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)

Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;

surf->compute(img_1, keypoints_1, descriptors_1);
surf->compute(img_2, keypoints_2, descriptors_2);

//-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
std::vector< DMatch > matches;
matcher.match(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches);

double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

//-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
for (int i = 0; i < descriptors_1.rows; i++)
{
    double dist = matches[i].distance;
    if (dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
    if (dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
}

printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist);
printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist);

//-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 2*min_dist,
//-- or a small arbitary value ( 0.02 ) in the event that min_dist is very
//-- small)
//-- PS.- radiusMatch can also be used here.
std::vector<DMatch> good_matches;

for (int i = 0; i < descriptors_1.rows; i++)
{
    if (matches[i].distance <= max(2 * min_dist, 0.02))
    {
        good_matches.push_back(matches[i]);
    }
}

//-- Draw only "good" matches
Mat img_matches;
drawMatches(img_1, keypoints_1, img_2, keypoints_2,good_matches,         img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1), 
    std::vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

//-- Show detected matches
imshow("Good Matches", img_matches);

for (int i = 0; i < (int)good_matches.size(); i++)
{
    printf("-- Good Match [%d] Keypoint 1: %d  -- Keypoint 2: %d  \n", i,    good_matches[i].queryIdx, good_matches[i].trainIdx);
}

waitKey(0);

return 0;
}


void readme()
{
   printf(" Usage: ./SURF_FlannMatcher <img1> <img2>\n");
}
```

Comment: SIFT and SURF have been moved to opencv_contrib repo, see link below

Comment: FYI https://www.nuget.org/packages/opencvcontrib/

Comment: I have included those, I have also included the link for the image, could have a look.

Comment: "unresolved externals" - means, you forgot to link the lib, opencv_xfeatures2d310.lib

Comment: aren't  all libraries included in opencv_world310d.?

Comment: okay, thanks for your help, I found the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

-The error screenshot hasn't showed up.

If you are using the contrib modules I believe you need to compile a build for yourself following the instructions on the Github page.

[Opencv Contrib Source](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib)

Comment: Its visible now, i have included the link. Sorry about that !!